# Pass ENV to Docker container running single command

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, environment-variables, alpine-linux

This prints blank:

```
docker run --rm --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 bash -c "echo $HELLO"
```

However this works:

```
docker run --rm -it --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 bash
# in the container
echo $HELLO
```

`HELLO` seems passed to the container though:

```
docker run --rm --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 env
```

Why is the first command not seeing `HELLO`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the double quotes, `$HELLO` will be evaluated by the docker host itself once the command got executed before going inside the container. So you need to either escape the dollar sign (`$`) using Backslash (`\`) which tells the bash that the `$` is a part of the command itself and no need to be evaluated by the current shell (which is the docker host in our case) or use single quotes (`''`) like this:

**Using single quotes**

```sh
$ docker run --rm --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 bash -c 'echo $HELLO'
world
```

**Using Backslash to escape**

```sh
$ docker run --rm --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 bash -c "echo \$HELLO"
world
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You sir are my hero. I wasted about two hours on this. And thanks for "evaluated by the docker host itself" bit. That clarifies everything.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing what you expect is because things are being evaluated before you expect them to be evaluated.

When you run:

```
docker run --rm --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 bash -c "echo $HELLO"
```

The `"echo $HELLO"` really isn't any different to bash than:

```
echo "echo $HELLO"
```

The shell (`bash`) parses double quotes (`"`) and things inside them. It sees `"echo $HELLO"` and replaces the variable `$HOME` with it's value. If `$HOME` is not defined, this evaluates to `echo`.

So,

```
echo "echo $HELLO"
```

is parsed and evaluted by your shell. Which then just runs this at the end:

```
echo "echo "
```

So the `"echo $HELLO"` in your docker command is evaluated to `"echo "` and *that's* what gets passed to the docker command.

What you want to do is to prevent your shell from evaluating the variable. You can do it a couple of ways:

1. You can use single quotes instead of double quotes. Your shell doesn't parse it; it will be passed to the `bash` inside the container as is:

   ```
   docker run --rm --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 bash -c 'echo $HELLO'
   ```
2. You can escape the `$` to avoid evaluating it in this shell and let the `bash` inside the docker container evaluate it:

   ```
   docker run --rm --env HELLO="world" ubuntu:18.04 bash -c "echo \$HELLO"
   ```